# How to limit the max execution time of a PHP script

Tags: php, time, limit, execution

I have a php script (file.php) that is used to counts banner impressions and returns an image, it end like this:

```
readfile('http://somedomain.com/banner.jpg');
mysql_close();
exit;
```

This file is used very much, and sometimes when the image is hosted on external server it load slow.

So to reduce my hosting usage i think to add a max execution time only on this script,
for example: if 5-10 seconds are passed, the script closes

i think that is possibile, but how?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

Comment: But why can't you simply point the HTML directly to this external file? Why does it have to be requested through your script? If you want to count banner impressions, read the logs for 'http://somedomain.com

Comment: Also http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested set_time_limit() but apparently readfile('http...'); doesn't honor this setting. The script was executed longer than the amount of time set via set_time_limit, but then aborted before the next "in-script" statment was executed.
But since php 5.2.1 the http url wrapper has a context option `timeout` which seems to do the trick.

```
mysql_close();
$ctx = stream_context_create( array(
    'http' => array(
        'timeout'  => 4.7 // in seconds
    )
);
readfile('http://somedomain.com/banner.jpg', false, $ctx);
exit;
```

see http://docs.php.net/context.http

Comment: Very useful! Thank you very much! Just one question, it work with https too?

Comment: @ipel : as stated in the documentation: `Context options for http:// and https:// transports`

Comment: just to be sure, to use the stream_context_create function with https pages, in my case, should i use: "steam_context_create(Array("http" => Array(..." or "steam_context_create(array('ssl' => array(.."???

Answer (score 1):

You can set the execution time on the top of your script with the **[set-time-limit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)** function.

Comment: much more useful answer than .ini file change, which affects ALL scripts (scary compatibility issue!) and may not be possible in shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Change you max_execution_time in you php.ini or add to your script ini_set('max_execution_time', 5);